# Can a Chronurgy Wizard upcast using Arcane Abeyance?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, spellcasting, wizard

Can arcane abeyance be used to upcast a spell? For example, can a bead made via arcane abeyance hold a 4th level fireball?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes, as long as the spell is cast no higher than 4th level.

Arcane Abeyance states:

> When you cast a spell using a spell slot of 4th level or lower

This is the only requirement. The rules for casting a spell state:

> When a character casts a spell, he or she expends a slot of that spell’s level *or higher*, effectively "filling" a slot with the spell. You can think of a spell slot as a groove of a certain size — small for a 1st-level slot, larger for a spell of higher level.
>
> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting. For instance, if Umara casts magic missile using one of her 2nd-level slots, that magic missile is 2nd level. Effectively, the spell expands to fill the slot it is put into.

A 4th level *fireball* is “a spell using a spell slot of 4th level or lower”, no ifs, ands, or buts. Nothing says you can’t cast a 4th level *fireball* into Arcane Abeyance, so when you do, a 4th level *fireball* comes out.

Comment: Thanks - apologies for not reading the arcane abeyance description more thoroughly